# How to end unresponsive processes that can't be taskkilled in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, process, unresponsive

How do I kill an unresponsive process or task in Windows when it becomes completely unresponsive *(window becomes a ligt grey, cursor a rotating blue ring)*?

- Clicking `[X]` or trying to end process in `taskmgr` has no effect [status is unresponsive].
- Task can't be killed using Process Explorer [`procexp`] or with any of the following:

  ```powershell
  TaskKill /f /pid %pid%

  TaskKill /f /im %exec.exe%
  ```

  ```powershell
  Stop-Process -Force -Name $name
  ```

Comment: Well, in such situations, I always know how to end them: `shutdown /r /t 0` and they are killed for good...

Comment: No replies? Then it seems the only right answer really is restarting...

Comment: For explanation see [Can't kill a sleeping process](https://superuser.com/questions/539920/cant-kill-a-sleeping-process) (Linux but applies here too).

Comment: But I am on Windows...

Comment: @harrymc That only explains it, I can confirm it's the same case, but it doesn't provide any real solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To end unkillable processes, use [`WMIC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) [Windows Management Instrumentation Console] in `cmd` or `powershell`, replace the variables with the PID/name of the process to kill:

- `cmd` *(variable: `%pid%`)*:

  ```powershell
  WMIC Process where ProcessID=%pid% delete
  ```
- `powershell` *(variable: `${name}`)*:

  ```powershell
  WMIC Process where Name="${name}.exe" delete
  ```

Comment: Good to know but no... the commands issued result in "Access denied", it's on admin console as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to use this code in a batch file :

```
@echo off 
Mode 90,3 & color 0B
Title Killing All Applications with Status equal to NOT RESPONDING
Taskkill /f /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
pause
```

---

***EDIT*** :

With Powershell you can do something like this :

```
Clear-Host
While ($True) {
$DateTime =$Null
$DateTime = (get-date).ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm:ss")
Try {
$Processes = Get-Process -EA Stop 
$nProcesses = @($Processes | ? { $_.Responding -eq $false })
#$nProcesses
} catch {            
    Write-Error "Failed to query processes. $_"            
 }            
    if($nProcesses) {            
        foreach($nProcess in $nProcesses) {            
            $nProcess | select ID,Name, MainWindowTitle,Path
            Stop-process -Force $nProcess        
    }            
} else {            
  Write-host "$DateTime - No non-responding processes found" -ForegroundColor Yellow            
 } 
 Start-Sleep -s 300
}
```

Comment: Did you read my question? I said the process can't be taskkilled, it does not accept terminating signals...