# How do you kill a process that can't be killed with kill -9?

Tags: linux, process, kill

Context: I need to create a floppy disk. I have a modern USB floppy disk drive, I want to run badblocks first to ensure that the "new" (new floppy disks are actually old new stock) floppy disk, actually works, before I write to it.

Badblocks starts, then halts, never finishes. I deem this disk as bad, and want to move on. However, badblocks refuses to die.

Here is my process:

```
root     3594810  0.0  0.0   5960  2048 ?        D    02:22   0:00 badblocks /dev/sdh
```

I've tried:

```
kill 3594810
kill -9 3594810
kill -15 3594810
strace -p 3594810 (I get no output at all)
pstree -p, I then killed the parent zsh and su process as well as the offending badblocks process, in a one-liner.
```

I can see this in dmesg, although I don't think this really helps eliminate the problem.

```
[423075.822587] INFO: task badblocks:3594810 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
```

1: Why is it so hard to kill a process like this?
2: How do I kill it?

No. I'm not going to reboot my system just because of this. It is quite incredible that modern Linux doesn't allow the user to reach into the system and kill a process if you really want to. I've tried so much at this point that it seems like writing my own kernel module that allows me to find a particular task struct and just tear it out would be the most effective solution at this point.

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/q/539920/432690) and [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/108618).

Comment: *In my experience* detaching the block device is often what it takes.

Comment: @Tom Yan Do you have a brief example? How do you detach it? Like this? echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/delete